# How can I add multi-dimensional arrays in javascript like this

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a javascript mini-project where users have to enter a number.

That number is an endpoint of coordinates. Last coordinate I will store in my array will be in format of [number, number]

For example, that number is 3.

I have to store this in an array.

[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]

For example, if number is 4, array need to looks like this:
[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4] [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4]

I hope you understand what I need. Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need two nested loops for this to work. In the code below, `i` variable represents the first number in the miniarray element, while `j` represents the second one. For each value of `i`, `j` will run `n` times and result in the array you want as follows:

```js
let n = 3;
let arr = [];

for(let i=1; i<=n; i++){
    for(let j=1; j<=n; j++){
    arr.push([i, j]);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following javascript code snippet.

```js
num = 5
arr=[]
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    temparr=[i,j]
    arr.push(temparr)
  } 
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: thank you! It works

Comment: Make sure you declare all your variables properly with `let` or `const`!

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helping you

```
const n = 5;
var array = Array(n).fill(0).map((o,index)=>o+index+1);
array.map(o=>arr1.flatMap(e=>[[o,e]]));
```

Comment: You should make a working snippet using the [<>] tool in the edit window, and try to explain what your code does because I imagine if the OP doesn't understand about loops they're certainly not going to understand concepts like `map` or `flatMap`. Add some links to MDN documentation. Make this a good answer rather than just a confusing code dump.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loops ... Try this one

```
function generateArray(int) {
  let array = [];
  let initial = 1;
  let numbers = [];
  while (initial <= int) {
    numbers.push(initial);
    initial++;
  }
  let finalArr = [];
  numbers.forEach(number => {
    let i = 1;
    while (i <= numbers.length) {
      array.push([number, i]);
      i++;
    }
  });
  return array;
}

console.log(generateArray(4))
```